# How to connect MPU-6050 gyroscope pins?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, gyro, gyroscope

I want use MPU-6050 in one of my projects. I have problem with some pins of this sensor.

CLKIN: What is this pin? I connect one oscillator with jumper and pull-down this pin. Datasheet say ground it when don't use it. Is this circuit for this pin is true? What is best for CLKIN?

AUX_DA and AUX_CL: These pins are for other I2C slave? Can I use these with pull-up and header (2 pin) for connecting extra device?

AD0: For change I2C address is this jumper and pull-up OK? Is there any problem for this pin?

FSYNC: What is this pin? I read in datasheet but I don't understand what is this and how is it work. Can I connect it direct to MCU and control it with MCU?

CPOUT and REGOUT: What are these pins? Datasheet say for connect with capacitors to ground. Can you say why?

If there is some problem or suggestion, I would be happy if you tell me.

[Datasheet](https://lionelectronic.ir/uploads/catalog/MPU-6050-InvenSense.pdf)

[image: MPU-6050 circuit]

Comment: Please include a link to the datasheet.

Comment: I add datasheet.

Comment: Did you know this https://randomnerdtutorials.com/arduino-mpu-6050-accelerometer-gyroscope/ and search schematics of this board https://components101.com/sensors/mpu6050-module datasheet https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

CLKIN is the external reference pin for a clock - it can be used to synchronize different devices to the same timing, if timing is critical. You can tie this to GND if you're only using the gyro.

AUX_DA and AUX_CL are for external sensors, to use more advanced sensors over what is currently contained within the gyro. These should be left floating.

AD0 can be GND or HIGH, it does not matter unless you have a large project, which I am assuming you don't. In the schematic it is tied to GND though, so it is not a Pull-Up as you said.

FSYNC is for frame synchronization, which is to do with sending and receiving data. If you do not already know how to use it, just connect it to ground. It produces a pulse when the first bit of data in the data frame is sent just so you know.

CPOUT is for the charge pump capacitor, which aims to temporarily boost current when needed, and REGOUT is for a filter capacitor, since high frequency signals have a low impedance path through capacitors.

Hope this helps!! Good luck